# Changing the data logging rate on a Tektronix DSO

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, analog, oscilloscope, digital-filter

Currently, for a continuous waveform, i am able to log data from the Tektronix TBA 1064 DSO as .csv files. The time interval between two samples currently is around 4 * E-08 (by default).

My requirement is to save 1000 samples of the signal values per second.
How do i change the sampling rate/data logging rate for the DSO so that it does not save a lot of clutter information as it is doing now.

Thanks

Comment: You have to change the time scaling parameter. I assume you're using tek visa. That should be called out in the programming manual.

Comment: @mcmiln The time scaling parameter would only change the resolution of the visible plot. Right? In other words, it would give a zoomed out view of the graph. Correct me.

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Are you trying to have a CSV file with 1000 points with a timestep of 1e-3? Are you trying to use an oscilloscope as a real-time data logger?

Comment: @W5VO The DSO is having a constant input being fed at one of it's channels. I am writing the numerical mean value of that signal  into a csv file. But i want to write at the rate of 1000 samples per second i.e. 1000 values of the same signal per second. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found concerning your scope...

http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/ugrad/389/scope-TDS%202000%20%20Manual.pdf

In it, they go into the sampling rate's change based in your scaling. While you are changing the timing you see, it isn't going to continue sampling very far beyond your window. This allows it to get better resolution by scaling back. See the attached image for an example...

[image: tek info]

Comment: So , if i tone down to 500 microsecond time base, it will sample at 500 kS/s. There is no way it samples at 1000 samples/sec?